# Running PyQt4 demos --- How?

Tags: pyqt4

I have recently downloaded and installed the latest release of PyQt4 for Windows. I have tested some simple PyQt4 examples and have seen no obvious problems. However, I am unable to execute the demos when I follow the directions given in the readme file of the demos:

Finding the PyQt Examples and Demos launcher
 ============================================

On Windows:

The launcher can be accessed via the Windows Start menu. Select the menu
 entry entitled "Examples and Demos" entry in the submenu containing PyQt4.

I have no problem finding and clicking on the "Examples and Demos" entry; but, I am never able to see a demo actually execute. I am using Windows Vista (32-bit) with Python 2.6?

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to `<PythonInstallation>\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\examples` in a cmd prompt and see if you can run the examples directly from there. That should at least give you some error messages if it doesn't work.

The louncher should be runnable from `demos\qtdemo\qtdemo.pyw`, but you also can run the single examples without the louncer.